# Socket.io emit message to Laravel

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, socket.io, laravel-5.1

I'm building an application which needs to emit messages back to the server. I'm using `Laravel` along with `predis` to handle server-side events.

Is it possible for `socket.io` to emit events which I can then listen for with `predis`?

Something like this on the client side:

```
io.emit('testChannel:someEvent', { dataOne: 'data', dataTwo: 'data' });
```

Then behind the scenes with `Laravel`:

```
public function listen()
{
    Redis::subscribe(['testChannel'], function($message) {
        dd($message);
    });
}
```

I wish I could provide more information, but I'm mightily confused by the entire process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the solution?